# Upper bound for induced norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I would like to obtain a tight upper bound for the following matrix norm:

$$ \| I - \frac{x x^T}{\|x\|_2^2} \| $$

where $x$ is a column vector. (Clearly, the second term is a rank-1 normalized matrix)

I was able to apply the triangle inequality to obtain a lower bound, i.e., for two matrices $A,B$, we have: $ \| A - B \| \geq \|A\| - \|B\|$ but am not sure how to do the upper bound.

Comment: What matrix norm are you using?

Comment: @kimchilover induced norm

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the link clearly says "one defines the corresponding induced norm or operator norm". If you don't have anything constructive to add, then, perhaps your help is not needed here? Feel free to find something else worthwhile to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your matrix $M$, let $V$ be the vector space it acts on.

Write $V=A\oplus B$ where $A$ is the span of $x$ (it's one dimensional) and $B=A^\perp$ is the set of vectors perpendicular to $x$.  If $v=a+b$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. then $Mv = Mb = b$.
Then we have $$ \frac {\|M(a+b)\|_2^2}{\|a+b\|_2^2} = \frac{\|b\|_2^2}{\|a\|_2^2+\|b\|_2^2} \le 1.$$

If $B$ is trivial (which happens only if $V$ is one dimensional) then $\|M\|=0$.  Otherwise, the bound $\|M\|=1$ is achieved by taking $v=b$ for non-zero $b\in B$.

Comment: thanks -- I see the second point. However, for any $x$ of dim at least 2, won't the nonzero eigenvalue of the normalized rank-1 matrix $\frac{xx^T}{\|x\|_2^2}$ be bounded by 1? And so max. singular value of identity minus this amount would be at most ($\leq$) 1? maybe I am overlooking something.

Comment: I worded my answer clumsily and incompletely; I will edit.  The matrix norm is $1$.  Your matrix is a projection onto the null space of $x$.  It has $n-1$ eigenvalues equal to 1 and one equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Triangle inequality works the other way as well, which is the most standard :

$$\|A - B\| \leq \|A\| + \|B\|$$

It all depends on how strict you want your bound approximation to be though.

Comment: thank you -- can it be formally shown that the norm is less than 1 since $xx^T$ is a normalized rank-1 PSD matrix (so the nonzero eigenvalue of $xx^T$ should be less than 1)? ty